# How can I have an empty date in a DateTime object?

Tags: php, date, datetime, object, default

When I get dates from a MySQL query, some of them are NULL, because unknown.
However, when I translate them into PHP using date_create, null dates are replaced by the today date by default, ehich is not what I want.
I tried to set the date properety Inside the date object to null or an empty string to no avail.
Is there some way I can get rid of this default date?

Comment: No! What do you think an "empty" DateTime object would look like? What would you actually do with an "empty" DateTime object?

Comment: Actually, I'm translating an application from ColdFusion to php. In CF all date fromating functions return an empty string if they receive an empty date, which is both consistant and very handful. In php this produces an error. I'm affraid I will have to check for null dates every time I have to use a date.

Answer (score 3):

It probably is being set to `null` whenever a date string cannot be parsed into the `DateTime` object.

I would like to suggest using `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

```
// Adjust the format to your requirements
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
```

Upon taking a better look on your question I figured you can also do:

```
if (is_null($date)) {
    $date = "0000-01-01";
}

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

This way, the date will be set to the first possible day (January 1 0000)

Answer (score 1):

```
$created_date = $date === null ? null : date_create($date);
```

This is a ternary expression that sets `$created_date` to null if `$date` is null, otherwise it sets it to `date_create($date)`.

Comment: Yes, but it will create a null object, I'd rather have a null date Inside a real date object.

Comment: Ok, but this will create a null object. I'd rather have a null date Inside a true Date object. But it's better than nothing, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean? How exactly would a null date object be expected to behave? What is the year, month or day of a null date? What happens when you add a null date to a real date?

Comment: If you really want an object that is not null but represents a null date then I would suggest you make a wrapper class for `DateTime` that checks if the object being wrapped is null and if it is handles it however you expect it to be handled.

Comment: This does not address the question made by the OP. Please remove your answer as it is not an answer to the question!